# Composite function with std::bind2nd in C++03

Tags: c++, bind, c++03

I would like to get some function/functor acts as a composite function/functor:

Specifically, I have functions `f(x, y)`, and  `g(u, v)`, and I want to create a function pointer or functor `h(t) = f(g(t,C1), C2)`, so that I can pass functor `h` into a for_each() loop, where C1, C2 are some constants.

Or, let's do it in my real example:
I have a function `double g(T1 u, T2 v)` which calculate something.   I want to loop through all `u` from a vector `vector<T1> vecInput`, with fixed 2nd argument `t2VConst`.  After calculating all these numbers, I want to save them into a vector `vector<double> results`.

I would like to do it with something similar to this:

`foreach(vecInput.begin(), vecInput.end(), std::bind2nd(&results::push_back, std::bind2nd(g, t2VConst)))`

Note that in this case, the `f(x,y)` function is really a member function `vector::push_back`.  (It seems that `push_back` only have one argument.  However, as a member function, it has an extra argument, which is the object itself.)

To make the case worse, I really have to do it in C++03, not C++11.  Is there any solution?   Moreover, I wish the solution can be cleaner (if it can be done in one line like above).

**UPDATE**

Related issue for `bind2nd()`:
I got compile error, and now I reduce it to a simpler code to look at it:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

#define CASE2   // choose define of CASE1 to CASE3

#ifdef CASE1
double g(double x, double y)   // 1. OK
#endif
#ifdef CASE2
double g(double &x, double y)  // 2. overload error
#endif
#ifdef CASE3
double g(double *x, double y)  // 3. OK
#endif
{
#ifdef CASE2
    x  = 5.0;
#endif
#ifdef CASE3
    *x = 5.0;
#endif
    // Note: no case1, since in case 1, x is a local variable, 
    // no meaning to assign value to it.

    return 3.0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double t = 2.0;
    double u;

#if defined(CASE1) || defined(CASE2)
    u = std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(&g), 3.0)(t);
#endif
#ifdef CASE3
    u = std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(&g), 3.0)(&t);
#endif
}
```

I don't know why CASE 2 fails...

Comment: I do not want to, but if it is really needed...

Comment: Wouldn't `std::transform(vecInput.begin(), vecInput.end(), std::back_inserter(results), std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(&g), t2VConst));` suffice in your case [as shown here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8167dd221c214de4)

Comment: It seems to me that you are correct... But I encountered a compiling error: `bind2nd` uses `binder2nd` which alerts an error: can not be overloaded.

Comment: I'd need to see entire the error message to tell what is wrong in your case

Comment: real tpe varies: `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\backward\binders.h:159: error: 'typename _Operation::result_type std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(typename _Operation::first_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::pointer_to_binary_function<const ucv::UPoint_<int>&, const cv::Vec<float, 4>&, void>; typename _Operation::result_type = void; typename _Operation::first_argument_type = const ucv::UPoint_<int>&]' cannot be overloaded
       operator()(typename _Operation::first_argument_type& __x) const
       `

Comment: This is because you can't create a binder for a function taking its parameter by reference

Comment: Ya. I seem to get the same results.  It's a pity that reference is forbidden.  The reference is essential since I don't want to copy the whole structure.  Yet a pointer is OK.  It's contradict with the preference of reference over pointer for OO language.

Comment: Piotr S.: you may post your suggestion of `std::tranform()` as an answer.  I will accept it.

Comment: In fact, for gcc, std::tr1::bind is even better way to do the job.  It supports reference. `std::transform(vecInput.begin(), vecInput.end(), std::back_inserter(results), std::tr1::bind(g, _1, t2VConst));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I have functions `f(x, y)`, and  `g(u, v)`, and I want to create a function pointer or functor `h(t) = f(g(t,C1), C2)`. I have to do it in C++03.*

It's not possible to compose functions using only the adapters available in the standard library of C++03. Obviously, nothing stops you from implementing this functionality on your own. However, if you want to utilize any of the existing libraries, and get a true one-liner, there are few alternatives:

#### Option #1: SGI extensions

libstdc++ is shipped with [the standard library extensions from SGI](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/). It provides several additional adapters and functors, namely: [`compose1`](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/unary_compose.html), [`compose2`](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/binary_compose.html) and [`constant1`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/group___s_g_iextensions.html#ga6bdf10e6611bb3d64aac73b0ccefba8). They can be combined in the following way:

```
#include <functional>
#include <ext/functional>

int f(int x, int y);
int g(int u, int v);
const int arg = 1;
const int C1 = 2;
const int C2 = 3;

__gnu_cxx::compose2(std::ptr_fun(&f)
                  , std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(&g), C1)
                  , __gnu_cxx::constant1<int>(C2)
                 )(arg);
```

#### Option #2: TR1 extensions

The initial implementation of C++11's `std::bind` can be also found in `tr1` extension libraries:

```
#include <tr1/functional>

int f(int x, int y);
int g(int u, int v);
const int arg = 1;
const int C1 = 2;
const int C2 = 3;

std::tr1::bind(&f
             , std::tr1::bind(&g
                            , std::tr1::placeholders::_1
                            , C1)
             , C2
            )(arg);
```

#### Option #3: Boost library

Boost.Bind library is probably the most portable solution:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

int f(int x, int y);
int g(int u, int v);
const int arg = 1;
const int C1 = 2;
const int C2 = 3;

boost::bind(&f, boost::bind(&g, _1, C1), C2)(arg);
```

---

> *The `f(x,y)` function is really a member function `vector::push_back`*

When it comes to binding a member function in C++03 you would normally use [`std::mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) together with [`std::bind1st`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) to bind the object parameter:

```
Class object;
std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Class::func), &object)(arg);
```

However, this will fail for member functions taking its parameter by reference. Once again, you could use Boost/TR1 instead:

```
boost::bind(&std::vector<double>::push_back
          , &results
          , boost::bind(&g, _1, C1)
          )(arg);
```

Note that when switching to C++11 you'd need to manually resolve overloaded `std::vector<double>::push_back`.

But fortunately, your use-case qualifies to be replaced by [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) algorithm with [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), that will take care of calling `push_back` member function of your vector for transformed arguments.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

int g(int u, int v);
const int C1 = 2;
std::vector<int> input, output;

std::transform(input.begin(), input.end()
             , std::back_inserter(output)
             , std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(&g), C1));
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da497f6419284cc7)

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that these library functions aren't magic, they just deduce rather involved types.

In your case, you don't need all this flexibility, if only because you know you'll need `vector::push_back`. Instead of deducing a rather involved type, just create a type explicitly to capture the function. There's even a library type which does this, `std::back_insert_iterator`, but in general you can do it yourself.

So, you'll end up with a template class that takes typenames T1 and T2, stores `&g`, `T2 C2`, and `std::vector<double>&`. It simply implements `void operator()(T1 t1) { v.pus_back(g(t1, C2)); }`.